# Replay()-like functionality but with the ability to displace stale values?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Wondering if anyone can think of an elegant solution to this use case:

I am consuming an observable (IObservable of type TEntity) which is providing me a stream of entities. If any of those entities are updated, then the provider of the observable will push down the updated entity.

I am using a Replay() on this stream so that I only need to subscribe to the underlying stream once and so that late subscribers can see all the values. The problem is that there is potential for a memory-leak here, because the Replay() will hold onto all the updates it sees, whereas all I need is the latest update for each entity.

I could replace the Replay() with a Scan() which allows me to maintain the latest updates only, but then I would have to push out a Dictionary of all the updates observed so far, rather than just the specific entity that has changed.

The only solution I can think of is to use a Scan() as above, but in the Scan() implementation I will push all updates into an Subject. Subscribers to the IObservable I will expose will receive a merge of the Snapshot stored in the Scan() dictionary plus any updates, as follows:

```
private Subject<Entity> _updateSubject = new Subject<Entity>();

private IObservable<Dictionary<string, Entity>> _subscriptionStream;

//called once on initialisation
private void CreateSubscription()
{
    IObservable<Entity> source = GetSomeLongRunningSubscriptionStream();

    _subscriptionStream = source
    .Scan(new Dictionary<string, Entity>(), (accumulator,update) =>
    {
        accumulator[update.ID] = update;

        _updateSubject.OnNext(update);

        return accumulator;
    })
    .Replay(1);
}

//called each time a consumer wants access to the stream
public IObservable<Entity> GetStream()
{
    return _subscriptionStream.Take(1).SelectMany(x => x).Select(x => x.Value)
    .Merge(_updateSubject.AsObservable());
}
```

Can anyone think of a more elegant solution with holds the state within a single stream rather than resorting to Subjects?

Thanks

************** Edit **************

As per my comment, I've gone with something similar to this. Let me know your thoughts

```
//called once on initialisation
private void CreateSubscription()
        {
            _baseSubscriptionObservable = GetSomeLongRunningSubscriptionStream ().Publish();

            _snapshotObservable = _baseSubscriptionObservable
                .Scan(new Dictionary<string,Entity>(), (accumulator, update) =>
                    {
                        accumulator[update.ID] = update;

                        return accumulator;
                    })
                .StartWith(new Dictionary<string, Entity>())
                .Replay(1);

            _baseSubscriptionObservable.Connect ();
            _snapshotObservable.Connect ();
        }

public IObservable<Entity> GetStream()
        {
            return _snapshotObservable.Take (1).Select (x => x.Values).SelectMany (x => x)
                .Merge (_baseSubscriptionObservable);
        }
```

Comment: Thinking about, perhaps I can just merge together 2 published streams. One can be the Snapshot issuing a Scan/replay(1) as above, and the other can just be a connect () which provides live updates.

Answer (score 3):

I generally like what you're doing, but there are a number of issues that I can see.

To start with you've split `CreateSubscription` and `GetStream` into two methods, with the idea that you'll have one underlying subscription to the `GetSomeLongRunningSubscriptionStream()` stream. Unfortunately, in this case, you'll have zero subscriptions regardless how many subscriptions you get to your final observable as `.Replay(1)` returns an `IConnectableObservable<>` which you need to call `.Connect()` on to begin the flow of values.

The next thing is that you're updating your accumulator with the latest value and then in `GetStream` you're adding in the latest value along with merging in a flattened stream of your accumulator. You're returning the latest value twice each time.

Here's how I would suggest that you do it:

```
private IObservable<IList<Timestamped<Entity>>> GetStream()
{
    return
        Observable
            .Create<IList<Timestamped<Entity>>>(o =>
                GetSomeLongRunningSubscriptionStream()
                    .Timestamp()
                    .Scan(
                        new Dictionary<string, Timestamped<Entity>>(),
                        (accumulator, update) =>
                        {
                            accumulator[update.Value.ID] = update;
                            return accumulator;
                        })
                    .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.Value).ToList())
                    .Replay(1)
                    .RefCount()
                    .Subscribe(o));
}
```

It's almost always best to avoid any state when using Rx (that isn't localized within the observable). So I've merged together `CreateSubscription` and `GetStream` into a single `GetStream` method and I've encapsulated the whole observable into a `Observable.Create`.

In order to avoid pushing out values twice and to facilitate your ability to know what the latest update is I've added a call to `.Timestamp()` to put the latest time an `Entity` was returned.

I've kept the `.Scan(...)` with the dictionary, but it is now a `Dictionary<string, Timestamped<Entity>>`.

For each value added/updated I then flatten the dictionary and return the underlying values as a list. At this point you could order the list to make sure that the latest values are either first or last to suit your needs.

I've then used the `.Replay(1).RefCount()` combination to turn the `IConnectableObservable<>` returned by `.Replay(1)` back into an `IObservable<>`, with the understanding that you'll dispose of the underlying subscription when all subscribers dispose. This is probably the most crucial part of your query. It should be done this way. This is the Rx way of ensuring that you avoid memory leaks.

If you desperately need to keep the underlying connection open then you would need to encapsulate all of your code within a class that implements `IDisposable` to clean up the `.Connect()` that you would require.

Something like this:

```
public class EntityStream : IDisposable 
{
    private IDisposable _connection = null;

    public EntityStream(IObservable<Entity> someLongRunningSubscriptionStream)
    {
        _stream =
            someLongRunningSubscriptionStream
            .Timestamp()
            .Scan(
                new Dictionary<string, Timestamped<Entity>>(),
                (accumulator, update) =>
                {
                    accumulator[update.Value.ID] = update;
                    return accumulator;
                })
            .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.Value).ToList())
            .Replay(1);

        _connection = _stream.Connect();
    }

    private IConnectableObservable<IList<Timestamped<Entity>>> _stream = null;

    public IObservable<IList<Timestamped<Entity>>> GetStream()
    {
        return _stream.AsObservable();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    if (_connection != null)
    {
        _connection.Dispose();
        _connection = null;
    }
    }
}
```

I so very rarely do this though. I would thoroughly recommend the doing the first method. You should only mix OOP and Rx when you have to.

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. First of all, you're correct in pointing out that this subscription will be created regardless of the number of subscribers. Luckily in this situation, this particular subscription is the driver for the entire application, so it will absolutely need to be created on startup and it'll last for the entire lifetime of the app. Also, unless I'm missing something, values are not being pushed out twice, as the Take(1) ensures new subscribers only get the current snapshot at that point in time, merged with updates.

Comment: For your solution, it seems you're pushing out the entire list each time? In my case this doesn't really make sense, as for each update, consumers only need to worry about that particular update, and not the entire snapshot, which they will already have observed.

Comment: +1 for talking about how this should be disposed, very good advice! I omitted this from the example. (although as above the subscription lasts the entire lifetime of the app. so is disposed on shutdown)

Comment: I've updated my question with a slightly cleaner solution, would appreciate any thoughts you had on it. Thanks

Comment: @Chris - I was slightly wrong - only the first value produced is duplicated. I tested the original code. I did miss the significance of the `Take(1)`. I had read the code as returning all of the items in the dictionary each time something was added. Your code isn't bad, but I would use something like my first solution and just create an empty subscription at the start of your app - that'll keep the observable open for all future subscribers and it's good practice.

Comment: I don't think your `Replay(1).RefCount()` in the first example has any actual impact, since it is inside the `Observable.Create` and thus there is no chance of it being shared with multiple subscribers...otherwise nice explanation

Comment: @Enigmativity The crux of the problem though is how to not resort to propagating the full list each time (Replay semantics in RX don't operate like this either). Imagine a consumer of this observable is pumping these entities into an ObservableCollection/ReactiveCollection which a grid is bound to. The bound collection would have to be cleared out on each update (or inspect the timestamps to try and work out what has changed).